# symfony 2 : can't execute data fixture doctrine:fixtures:load

Tags: symfony

I have project developed with Symfony2.8. It works locally. I am trying to execute doctrine:fixtures:load but I get this error :

[image]

Comment: It looks like the fixtures are fine, the problem is with you swift mailer setup.  Possible fix for you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420937/uncaught-exception-swift-transportexception-with-message-connection-could-not (downvoted answer as it appears you are using wamp)

Comment: I really don't understand why a swiftmailer exception is thrown in a fixtures loading script.. Are you explicitely throwing it in your script ? can you post your Epx\Bundle\SubscriptionBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadData.php file ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server (wampserver) is not working properly. Indeed the application (Symfony app) is not able to communicate to it via doctrine that is why it display: 
`connection could not be established with localhost...` So you simple have to check what is wrong with your localhost server. I suggest:

- Restart wamp
- Restart your PC (if restarting wamp does not work)
- Reinstall wamp (if restarting your PC does not work)
- Search on web ...(if any of above does not work...)